# Does CircleCI use Docker "host" networks for connecting from the primary container to service containers?

Tags: docker, networking, continuous-integration, github-actions, circleci

I'm trying to understand how CI/CD providers implement Docker networking. When reading the docs for CircleCI and GitHub Actions, they describe how to use service containers (like PostgreSQL etc) differently.

CircleCI (https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/executor-types/) says:

> All containers run in a common network and every exposed port will be
> available on localhost from a primary container.

They have an example config that shows accessing a MongoDB service container from the primary container on `localhost`:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
    # Primary container image where all steps run.
     - image: buildpack-deps:trusty
    # Secondary container image on common network. 
     - image: mongo:2.6.8-jessie
       command: [mongod, --smallfiles]

    working_directory: ~/

    steps:
      # command will execute in trusty container
      # and can access mongo on localhost
      - run: sleep 5 && nc -vz localhost 27017
```

GitHub Actions (https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/guides/about-service-containers) says:

> When you run jobs in a container, GitHub connects service containers to the job using Docker's user-defined bridge networks.

They have examples elsewhere in their docs that show how to connect to the container. Here's one for PostgreSQL:

```yaml
name: PostgreSQL service example
on: push

jobs:
  # Label of the container job
  container-job:
    # Containers must run in Linux based operating systems
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Docker Hub image that `container-job` executes in
    container: node:10.18-jessie

    # Service containers to run with `container-job`
    services:
      # Label used to access the service container
      postgres:
        # Docker Hub image
        image: postgres
        # Provide the password for postgres
        env:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        # Set health checks to wait until postgres has started
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5

    steps:
      # Downloads a copy of the code in your repository before running CI tests
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # Performs a clean installation of all dependencies in the `package.json` file
      # For more information, see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci

      - name: Connect to PostgreSQL
        # Runs a script that creates a PostgreSQL client, populates
        # the client with data, and retrieves data
        run: node client.js
        # Environment variable used by the `client.js` script to create a new PostgreSQL client.
        env:
          # The hostname used to communicate with the PostgreSQL service container
          POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
          # The default PostgreSQL port
          POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
```

Here, the hostname of the PostgreSQL container is `postgres` (not `localhost`) because that label was chosen under `services:`.

CircleCI's docs don't explicitly describe what they do for networking, but does this mean that they're using the "host" networking mode (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-host)? And, since the Docker documentation states:

> Publishing ports and linking to other containers only works with the default (bridge).

Why does CircleCI not require you to include ports to be mapped in the config? Could they be parsing the Dockerfile for the containers and looking for `EXPOSE` directives and doing this automatically?

Comment: Hi Matt, Did you find answer ? I do have same question and keen to know answer.

Comment: Didn't find an answer yet, no. This wasn't a blocker for anything work-related, so I didn't need to urgently find and answer. It was just something I was curious about back when I asked it. I'm actually surprised the question hasn't been closed because it's pretty subjective. I notice that I asked a lot of "how could they be..." etc. Since asking this question, I have learned more about networking. I think that there could be many ways that CircleCI and GitHub Actions do things at a low level so that at a high level users can use them this way. It might be that only they could answer it.